# Why random of 0 to 4 is 1 most of times?

Tags: java

I am using a simple random calculations for a small range with 4 elements.

```
indexOfNext = new Random().nextInt(4); //randomize 0 to 3
```

When I attach the debugger I see that for the first 2-3 times **every time** the result is 1.

Is this the wrong method for a small range or I should implement another logic (detecting previous random result)?

**NOTE**: If this is just a coincidence, then using this method is the wrong way to go, right? If yes, can you suggest alternative method? Shuffle maybe? Ideally, the alternative method would have a way to check that next result is not the same as the previous result.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If so, then this is the wrong method to determine random number.

Comment: Odd, it doesn't do that for me.  Mine is completely random looking.

Comment: @sandalone looks like you're misunderstanding *coincidence*. It is, in fact, a random value, and you won't know which value will retrieve until you call it. Also, if you mean to get random value between 0 and 4, use `nextInt(5)` and **do not create the `Random` every time**, instead use one single instance and call its `nextInt` method where you need it.

Comment: Your range here is of 3 elements not 4. i.e. [0,3[

Comment: @Naili Yes, I know. I fixed the title 5min ago. Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's actually going on without seeing your actual implementation and output. There are several different answers which may or may not be correct depending on what you're seeing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't create a `new Random()` each time, create one object and call it many times.

This is because you need one random generator and many numbers from its
random sequence, as opposed to having many random generators and getting
just the 1st numbers of the random sequences they generate.

Comment: Wow, this may be it! I will check.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This is because the OP needs one random generator and many numbers from its random sequence, as opposed to having many random generators and getting just the 1st numbers of the sequences they generate.

Comment: What I mean is that this answer looks more like a comment than a real answer. Just read the other answers providing an explanation on the problem and why the proposed solution will work.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Could be. Whose explanation is right? I want to learn something.

Comment: Bathsheba's and chubbsondubs' answers. Also, refer to the official javadoc of [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class.

Comment: Hm... OK. I see `public Random() { this(++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()); }` If this does not generate a random seed, I don't know if it's not implementation's fault.

Comment: The root cause is still not quite clear to me. I guess I had learned this rule once just as an axiom :) And that's why I stated it here in pretty much the same way.

Comment: @peter.petrov: Seeding the PRNG with system time (plus epsilon, right) is definitely the implementer's fault.

Comment: @Piskvor (implementor of the Java language, not the OP, of course)

Answer (score 9):

You're abusing the random number generator by creating a new instance repeatedly. (This is due to the implementation setting a starting random number value that's a very deterministic function of your system clock time). This ruins the statistical properties of the generator.

You should create one instance, then call `nextInt` as you need numbers.

Comment: Actually (to be sarcastically pedantic), creating new instances doesn't ruin the statistical properties of the generator in any way. _Each_ generator still has these beautiful properties, though they are ignored ;-)

Comment: Both you and @peter.petrov are right. Since he replied before you I am making his reply as an answer and upvoting yours.

Comment: +1 from me even though the root cause is still not quite clear to me

Answer (score 5):

One thing you can do is hold onto the Random instance.  It has to seed itself each time you instantiate it and if that seed is the same then it will generate the same random sequence each time.

Other options are converting to SecureRandom, but you definitely want to hold onto that random instance to get the best random number performance.  You really only need SecureRandom is you are randomly generating things that have security implications.  Like implementing crypto algorithms or working around such things.

Comment: It does have to seed each time, but the API says "This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor."

Comment: And I did say possible.  Holding on the Random instance doesn't completely explain what the OP describes, but it's a place to start.  We know the quality of random numbers coming out of Random isn't fantastic, but pretty good.

Comment: @azurefrog: "very likely to be distinct" - after what I've seen in most places, I read that as "we're seeding it with system time."

Comment: From memory I've seen the code for Random and it's System time + a static incrementing variable to handle issues when two Random objects are instantiating at the same time (ms).  But it's been a while since I looked at it.

Comment: it's not `possible it will generate the same random sequence each time`, it's certain. Pseudo-random number generators with the same seed are guaranteed to return the same numbers in the same order.

Answer (score 3):

"Random" doesn't mean "non-repeating", and you cannot judge randomness by short sequences. For example, imagine that you have 2 sequences of 1 and 0:

```
101010101010101010101010101010101
```

and

```
110100100001110100100011111010001
```

Which looks more random? Second one, of course. But when you take any **short sequence** of 3-4-5 numbers from it, such sequence will look less random than taken from the first one. This is well-known and researched paradox.

Comment: This actually seems to be the most likely explanation for what OP is seeing. The answers about creating one instance and then calling `nextInt()` on it, while correct that that is the better practice, don't really explain why OP would get seeming non-random output.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard absolutely. Java uses pretty good methods of seeding and generating random numbers, so it doesn't matter if you create one instance or many unless you don't set the seed value explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

A pseudo-random number generator requires a seed to work. The seed is a bit array which size depends on the implementation. The initial seed for a `Random` can either be specified manually or automatically assigned.

Now there are several common ways of assigning a random seed. One of them is `++currentSeed`, the other is current timestamp.

It is possible that java uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the timestamp and initialize the seed with it. Since the resolution of the timestamp is at most a millisecond (it differs on some machines, WinXP AFAIK had 3ms) all `Random` instances instantiated in the same millisecond-resolution window will have the same seed.

Another feature of pseudo-random number generators is that if they have the same seed, they return the same numbers in the same order.

So if you get the first pseudo-random number returned by several `Random`s initialized with the same seed you are bound to get the same number for a few times. And I suspect that's what's happening in your case.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the number 1 has a 30% chance of showing its self which is more than other numbers. You can read [this](http://news.dice.com/2014/01/24/generating-random-numbers-javas-random-class/) link for more information on the subject.

You can also read up on [Benford's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benfords_law).

Comment: I don't think that applies here. In this case a PRNG with uniform distribution picking numbers from 0, 1, and 2 (as in OP's example) should pick 1 a third of the time (with some margin of error, but far closer than 30%).

Comment: @Lunchbox: That's quite the opposite: in "physical" data sources, the first digit has a 30% chance to be `1`. PRNGs, on the other hand, strive to output normally distributed data: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: @Piskvor A minor point: I believe that most of the methods in `Random` provide _uniform,_ rather than _normal,_ distribution. `Random#nextGaussian()` gives a normal distribution, however.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: Good point indeed; hence "strives to output" (instead of "outputs").

Comment: `1` have more chances to appear as first digit in numbers without leading zero, but it is out of discussed topic.